# Function which puts strings out of vars together and puts them into an input doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I was working on a Web C++ Junk Code Generator and it was just working fine and executed the function on Click of the button which had the tag and put the generated variable in the input, but now it doesn't anymore.  I was working on the Tool on CodePen, so here's the link.

[codepen link](http://nex.li/p$od!au)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code I added `var randfloat5 = "";` after line 25. I think it solved your problem and the code worked.

Comment: I literally just noticed that 5 seconds ago. Thanks, tho.

Comment: Ah, and the 5 was a typo. Wanted it to be a 4.